# I am getting this error while I am running my program what should I do? My program is based on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, build.gradle

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4uB.png)

I changed this to 4.3.13, 4.3.15 but nothing worked for me please guide me to overcome this issue.
The issue is in the build.grade file of root android project I have done everything to overcome this issue but cannot find a possible way.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is with the notation, not the version.

Try replacing it with
`com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0` or`com.google:gms-google-services:4.4.0`.